# The jsonlite::fromJSON(data.json) function do not work within a package function

Tags: php, package, jsonlite, opencpu

The simplified code of my R script is:

```
library(jsonlite)

function_name <- function(data.json)
{
 tmp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data.json)
}
```

This runs perfect on my local PC. Then I build a package, upload the package to an ubuntu server and use the function within an OpenCPU/php environment. My package includes further functions stored in mathematic packages like randomForest, e1071, ...
All mathematic packages work perfect, but the jsonlite::fromJSON(data.json) interrupts the programme. The same is true for the alternative package rjson. I don't known where to look for the reason of this strange error.

Comment: can you share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that `jsonlite` is installed in your Ubuntu server and `opencpu` can run it

Add the package that you need to the `DESCRIPTION` file structure and delete the `library(jsonlite)` part of code of your script.

```
function_name <- function(data.json) {
  tmp <- fromJSON(data.json)
}
```

I suggest to use `Roxygen2` for import and exports functions depending of your needs

You can read about that and learn how to make the structure of a package in the online book [R packages by Hadley Wickham](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)

Comment: I controlled everything and did not find the error. Now a wrote a simple example to have a better look on the problem. Please see my further question: php guzzle OpenCPU POST request for a simple R package function stucks during execution